# message properties file in custom jsf component

Tags: jsf

i'm developing a custom jsf component a want to store messages i a properties file and want get messages stored in it by java code. Must i config faces-config? and how to get message bundle??

Answer (score 1):

Just drop it in classpath and use [`java.util.Properties`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) or [`java.util.ResourceBundle`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) for configuration settings or localized content respectively. Here are examples assuming that you've dropped the `filename.properties` file in `com.example` package.

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("com/example/filename.properties"));
// ...
```

or

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResouceBundle.getBundle("com.example.filename");
// ...
```